# No match operator for 'operator *' in Matrix

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operators

I have a matrix class like below:

```
template <size_t M, size_t N, typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix<M, N, T> operator +(const Matrix<M, N, T>& B) const;
    template <size_t P> Matrix<M,P,T> operator*(const Matrix<N, P, T>& B) const;
    template <typename T2> operator T2() const;  

private:
  T data[M][N];
};

// ... the body is in header file too  ...//
```

The body has written fine, and everything works well.
When I define two Matrices as below:

```
Matrix < 10, 10, int> m1;
Matrix < 10, 10, float> m2;

m1 + m2;  // OK
m1 * m2;  // error: no match for 'operator*' in 'm1 * m2'
```

The first '+' operator works well, because an **implicit casting** has performed on it.
but for second '*' operator for different value types, an error occurs.

> error: no match for 'operator*' in 'm1 * m2'

Any idea ?!

**UPDATE:**
All code is in header file. I have no problem but for '*' operator.

What you can say about '+' operator? I know everything about template/operators/casting... but this problem is like a bug for my gcc compiler!? I wrote a cast-operator and this operator calls before '+' operator, but i dont know why it dose not perform for '*' operator!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is more or less classic.  The overload resolution starts by
building a list of possible functions; in this case, functions named
`operator*`.  To do this, it adds all `operator*` functions which are in
scope to the list, and it tries to instantiate all function templates by 
applying type deduction; if type deduction succeeds, it adds the
instantiation of the template to the list.  (A function template is
**not** a function.  An instantiation of the function template is a
function.)

The rules for template type deduction are different than those used in
overload resolution.  In particular, only a very small set of
conversions are considered.  User defined conversion operators are not
considered.  The result is that in `m1 * m2`, type deduction for
`operator*` fails (since it would require a conversion which isn't
considered).  So no instantiation of the function template is added to
the list, and there is no other `operator*`.

More generally: you're `operator T2()` wouldn't allow type deduction
even if it were allowed; there are a infinite number of conversions
which would match `operator*`.  I suspect, in fact, that you've made it
too general; that you want an `operator Matrix<M, N, T2>()`.  (Not that
this will help here, but there are contexts where it might eliminate an
ambiguity.)

You might be able to make it work by defining a:

```
template<size_t P, tyepname OtherT>
Matrix<M, P, T> operator*( Matrix<N, P, T> const& rhs ) const;
```

, then doing the conversion inside the operator*.  (I haven't tried it,
and am not sure, but I think your existing `operator*` should be
considered “more specialized”, and thus be chosen when type
deduction succeeds for both.)

Having said this, I think the way you're doing it is the wrong approach.
Do you really want the return types of `m1 * m2` and `m2 * m1` to be
different.  For starters, I'd require the client code to make the
conversion explicit (which is the case in your current code); if you do
want to support the implicit conversions, I think you need to make the
`operator*` a global, use some sort of simple meta-programming to
determine the correct return type (i.e. given Matrices of `long` and
`unsigned`, you might want to have a return type of `unsigned long`,
since this is what mixed type arithmetic with these types gives
otherwise), convert both sides to the target type, and do the arithmetic
on it.  A lot of work for what is probably not a very important or
useful feature.  (Just my opinion, of course.  If your clients really
want the mixed type arithmetic, and are willing to pay for it...)

Answer (score 2):

The implicit cast is the culprit in your example (`m1 * m1` works). While I am not language-firm enough to tell you exactly why, I suspect that the combination of a templated operator* method (which doesn't specify the type exactly) and a necessary type conversion has too much ambiguity. The compiler is told that it can convert your matrix into any type, and that a templated family of types could be valid arguments for `operator*`. *I* would have problems determining which `operator*` to call from these methods. Inserting a `static_cast` as `m1 * static_cast< Matrix<10,10,int> >(m2)` confirms this suspicion.

The [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) library is a fairly mature and very good matrix library, and they also don't make implicit scalar conversions. Rather, they have used a cast method:

```
template <typename Scalar> Matrix<M,N,Scalar> cast() const;
```

In your example, you'd write:

```
m1.cast<float>() * m2;
```

Comment: Yes, i tried something like `m1.cast<float>()` before, and it was good. but the benefit of implicit-casting is casting like float->float can dropped by compiler. but when i use `cast<float>()` the casting will run even for float->float.

Comment: @MasoudM: Add a specialization for unnecessary casts. `boost::is_same<Scalar,T>` is your friend.